# Can I just backup my data in Time Machine before I update into an OS update?

Tags: backup, time-machine, software-update

When I attempted to update my MacOS to Catalina, I had a devastating 2 days worth of troubleshooting my Mac. It says it can't install the current update. I've reworked with Apple Support back and forth only to find myself on the same error.

Luckily, I was able to reboot to my old OS (before the tragedy) and backup all my files. I've learned my lesson to create a backup before updating.

As I read through some questions about Time Machine, I realized it keeps on updating itself through time. My question is... can I just create a Time Machine backup right before I update my OS?

I make changes on my laptop every day. Since most of the files I make/download are usually deleted when I'm sure I'm done with it. I don't want Time Machine to keep on backing up files that won't be of use and might just take up a lot of space in my backup. Please let me know if this is as safe step.

Comment: 1. You can always create an immediate backup, by choosing "Create backup..." in the menubar  (if the Time Machine menulet is visible). 2. A backup every now and then is no backup!